Chocolatey unable to upgrade librewolf - incompatible dependency
I'm trying to update Librewolf with Chocolatey. But I get dependency errors:
C:\Users\Lauloque>choco upgrade librewolf --force
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Upgrading the following packages:
librewolf
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.

You have librewolf v109.0.1.2 installed. Version 125.0.3.1 is available based on your source(s).
[NuGet] One or more unresolved package dependency constraints detected in the Chocolatey lib folder. All dependency constraints must be resolved to add or update packages. If these packages are being updated this message may be ignored, if not the following error(s) may be blocking the current package operation: 'python 3.12.1 constraint: python3 (= 3.12.1)'
Re-attempting package dependency resolution using additional available package information...
[NuGet] One or more unresolved package dependency constraints detected in the Chocolatey lib folder. All dependency constraints must be resolved to add or update packages. If these packages are being updated this message may be ignored, if not the following error(s) may be blocking the current package operation: 'python 3.12.1 constraint: python3 (= 3.12.1)'
Unable to resolve dependency 'kb2919355': Unable to find a version of 'kb2919355' that is compatible with 'KB2999226 1.0.20161023 constraint: kb2919355 (>= 1.0.20160915)', 'vcredist140 14.0.23026 constraint: kb2919355 (>= 1.0.20160915)'.

Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - librewolf - Unable to resolve dependency 'kb2919355': Unable to find a version of 'kb2919355' that is compatible with 'KB2999226 1.0.20161023 constraint: kb2919355 (>= 1.0.20160915)', 'vcredist140 14.0.23026 constraint: kb2919355 (>= 1.0.20160915)'.

I tried the advices of Chocolatey Software Docs | Dependency Troubleshooting in Chocolatey CLI but it seems to not get better:
C:\Users\Lauloque>choco upgrade kb2919355
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Upgrading the following packages:
kb2919355
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
KB2919355 v1.0.20160915 is the latest version available based on your source(s).

C:\Users\Lauloque>choco upgrade KB2999226
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Upgrading the following packages:
KB2999226
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
KB2999226 v1.0.20181019 is the latest version available based on your source(s).

Here's the chocolatey.log of the month:
chocolatey.log - Pastebin.com

Can you upgrade other packages? Check a bunch, especially ones that have dependencies. Did you upgrade (and the command failed) any other package before this? Chocolatey can get stuck in some bugged dependency nonsense state if you e.g. upgrade a meta package while realted install one fails to complete.

So... I upgraded python, it worked (just updated from 3.12.1 to 3.12.3), then I ran choco upgrade all, it found librewolf and mkvtoolnix as outdated, and upgraded them successfully.... I don't understand why it worked there?

Did you do any system restarts or anything like that in the meanwhile?

I shutdown my computer every night, including the one before I read your first comment. But just before trying your suggestion I tried upgrading librewolf again and was still having an error.

Well, that wasn't my suggestion. It was trying other libraries. Chocolatey fixes itself sometimes after system restarts. So this is kind of unanswerabe now as the exact cause isn't known.
